# My plugins are ending up above the header?

Tags: plugins

Trying to start writing some plugins, however everytime i use the shortcode that calls my function plugin, the function ends up above the header on that page, instead of right where i placed the shortcode.

Here is an example of what i used:

[image]

Comment: Please don't paste in a screenshot of your code; paste in the actual code, which will be more accessible and also much easier for us to diagnose.

Answer (score 0):

**Shortcodes should `return` their content, never `echo` it.**

From the [`add_shortcode()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) docs:

> Note that the function called by the shortcode should *never* produce an output of any kind. Shortcode functions should *return* the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode. Producing the output directly will lead to unexpected results.

But the functions you appear to be using—[`the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_title/) and [`the_date()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_date/)—both `echo` their output by default. Consider using [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) and [`get_the_date()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/) instead. You'll need to refactor some of the rest of your code too, but this should be a good starting point.